# Accessing an array inside of JSON object from reviver

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have a `JSON` object formatted like `{"Foo": ["B","A","R"]}`

I am trying to access the values of the array like this:

```
var json = '{"Foo": ["B","A","R"]}';

expression = JSON.Parse(json, function(key, value){
          if(key == "Foo"){
             console.log(value.length); // logs "3"
             console.log(value[1]);     // logs "undefined"
           } 
       });
```

If I ask for the length of value it returns the correct length of the array, but if I ask for the value it returns `undefined` and I am not quite sure why.There are other values in the `JSON` that I am able to access just fine, but they are not arrays. Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is this your actual code? `value` !== `Valid`

Comment: You have an issue with the JSON structure var json = '{"Foo": ["B","A","R"]}'; Double quotes and single quotes are conflicting

Comment: Its not my actual code, the actual code works with the rest of the JSON values, but not the one with the array.

Comment: `var json = '{"Foo": ["B","A","R"]}'; console.log(JSON.parse(json).Foo);`

Comment: Is your objective simply to access the value in the array, or do you have some specific reason to use the second optional "reviver" parameter to `JSON.parse`, such as wanting to filter or transform the object while it is being parsed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) like this:

```
var json = '{"Foo":["B","A","R"]}';
var object = JSON.parse(json);
// object is now and object containing the data from 'json'

var expression = object["Foo"][1]; // object["Foo"] refers to the
                                   // value with key "Foo"
```

(Calling `JSON.parse` with a callback parameter is an advanced feature for transforming the JSON object, not reading it. In almost all cases, though, you want to use it like the above code, with no callbacks.)

Comment: I am trying to parse it into an object so that I can take them and build another object based on what the JSON holds, it that makes sense. However I am going to try it without the callback. Thanks!

Comment: This does not answer the question why the original code does not work.

Comment: @torazaburo Indeed it does not, but IMO the problem was that the callback shouldn't be used to simply read a JSON object anyways. Answers aren't necessarily about *answering a literal question*, it's about *solving a problem*, which I think my answer tried to do.

Comment: Agreed, but it's a also a reasonable assumption that this is a minimal example showing a problem he was having with using the reviver for some valid usecase. Only way to know is to ask him.

Comment: I don't know if I'd say it's bad practice to use the second param, if it were you could bet Crockford wouldn't have included it. Maybe the data structure is misaligned to his usage. The second param is indeed meant to be used when reading JSON.

Comment: @cchamberlain I'm not claiming it's *bad practice* to use the second parameter, as I do believe there are valid uses for it; I'm just saying it's not something you should be using unless you actually have a reason to use it instead of the single-argument version.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer, if you simply want to retrieve the second element of `Foo`, you can do that easily enough after parsing using standard property access techniques such as `obj.Foo[1]`.

Assuming you really want to use the optional second "reviver" parameter to `JSON.parse`, you need to **return the value** from the "reviver" callback;

```
expression = JSON.Parse(json, function(key, value){
  if (key == "Foo"){
     console.log(value[1]);
  } 
  return value;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it appears you can't access value[1] but you can access value.length is (as mentioned by user663031) you don't have a return value.

The reviver function replaces one value with another, if no return is specified all functions will return undefined. The order the reviver receives the values is: first each of the values in the array separately, then the array.

In your code each value has already been replaced with "undefined", so the array has three undefined values as reported by the length. `value[1]` really is returning the value at position 1 but it is set to "undefined".

Answer (score 1):

When the json string has arrays the reviver function is called with *index, [Object]* as key, value parameters .

This sniped of code that filter object properties on parse phase will be helpful:

```
    var json = '{"_embedded": [{"a":"A","b":"B","links": {"c":"C"}},{"a":"A2", "b":"B2","links": {"c":"C2"}}]}';
    var schemaNames=["_embedded", "a"];

    var result= JSON.parse(json, function(k, v) {
      console.log(k,v);
      if ("" === k){
        return v;
      }
      // On arrays k is a number
      else if (schemaNames.indexOf(k) > -1  || !isNaN(k)){
          return v;
      }
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

> Output: {"_embedded":[{"a":"A"},{"a":"A2"}]}

https://jsfiddle.net/pdorgambide/vphbmtk1/

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
   var json = {'foo' : ['B', 'A', 'R']};
   $.each(json, function(key, value){if(key == 'foo'){console.log(value[1]);}});
```

you already have a json object so no need to parse it again.

Comment: I am actually reading it from a file, which is why I have to parse it.

Comment: What is `$.each`? What is a "JSON object"? Since `json` is a string, why would he not have to parse it?

Comment: lol jQuery in 2016.. just use built-in Object.keys / Object.entries and .forEach or .map.